# Why can File.listFiles return null when called on a directory?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, file-listing

I'm creating an Android app, and I want to list the files in a directory. I do this by calling

```
File[] files = path.listFiles(new CustomFileFilter());
```

`path` is a `File` object, which is created by calling

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

When I then try to get the length of the `files` array by calling

```
int length = files.length;
```

This line gives me a `NullPointerException`, because `files` is null.

I have checked if the `path` which I try to list the files in exists by calling

```
System.out.println("Path exists: " + path.exists());
```

And when I run the app, it prints

```
Path exists: true
```

in the Android Studio console, so the directory exists.

I've also printed the path name, which is

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download
```

So the `path` is a directory, and not a file.

I have no idea about why I'm getting a `NullPointerException`, because the `path` is a directory.

**EDIT**: The `CustomFileFilter` class looks like this:

```
public class CustomFileFilter implements FileFilter {

    // Determine if the file should be accepted
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        // If the file isn't a directory
        if(file.isDirectory()) {
            // Accept it
            return true;
        } else if(file.getName().endsWith("txt")) {
            // Accept it
            return true;
        }
        // Don't accept it
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably due to `CustomFileFilter` class you are not getting any file in Array. try same code with `path.listFiles()` method

Comment: Oh, forget to add the `CustomFileFilter` class to the question.

Comment: Show the output of `path.isDirectory()` and `path.canRead()`. Just because you say it's a file doesn't make it a file.

Comment: still show same exception when using `path.listFiles()` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK If no files match, the method returns an empty array, not null.

Comment: @chrylis: see here [File.listFiles](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) return `an array of files or null.`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I *did* check the Javadocs. Read them again. Specifically, read the description of *when* it can return null. It's not when you don't match any files in a directory.

Comment: @chrylis: but OP is using android api instead of java. In java i agree with you

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK The Android `java` namespace operates identically to the same API on traditional Java except in a few specifically-noted instances. Both the Android and Oracle docs specify identical behavior here.

Comment: As per the javadoc. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(), it can return null in case it is not identified as a directory.

Can you check path.isDirectory()?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This permission allow you to read files; if you don't use this permission then `listFiles()` and `list()` will both throw `NullPointerException`.

And here is an example of showing all files in `/storage/emulated/0/Download`:

```
   String dir = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/";
        File f = new File(dir);
        String[] files = f.list();
        for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++){
            Log.d("tag", files[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Not sure but shouldn't accessing the file result in IOException instead of NullpointerException in case the user does not have the read permission?

Comment: @Sashwat by removing this permission NullpointerException will be threw

Answer (score 5):

make sure you followed the [Saeed Masoumi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27874917/11669081)’s answer, and if you still have the problem it is because you have set Target API 29 or higher.

add this property in your application tag of Manifest file and it will work.

```xml
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

According to [google’s App compatibility features for data storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/compatibility) :

Before your app is fully compatible with scoped storage, you can temporarily opt out by using one of the following methods:

- Target Android 9 (API level 28) or lower.
- If you target Android 10 (API level 29) or higher, set the value of requestLegacyExternalStorage to true in your app's manifest file:

```xml
    <manifest ... >
      <!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting
           Android 10 or higher. -->
        <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
          ...
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

To test how an app targeting Android 9 or lower behaves when using scoped storage, you can opt in to the behavior by setting the value of requestLegacyExternalStorage to false.

Comment: I was in a big trouble, this help me... Thank you very much..

Answer (score 3):

For those who are working on android SDK>23, you need to grant the permissions by code:
use something like:

```
 boolean grantedAll = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
if (!grantedAll)
   {
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
   }
```