# getExternalStorageState.listFiles() returns null

Tags: android

First off I thought this issue might be experienced thousands of times and already solved long time ago. However it was not the case, I red the following posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831762/java-io-file-listfiles-returns-null-from-windows-cmd-but-not-as-eclipse-proj), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874706/why-can-file-listfiles-return-null-when-called-on-a-directory), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714058/file-exists-and-is-directory-but-listfiles-returns-null) and others but none of the helped.

So here is my case.
I am working on chat application that allows users to attach files, to make that happen I am developing file explorer but I keep running into `NullPointerException`. Here is my code.

```
String extState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if(extState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File[] sdDirList = sd.listFiles();
}
```

Here I am checking if external storage is mounted and it returns true. However it keeps throwing `NullPointerException` because `sd.listFiles()` return `null`.

in manifest I have the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am testing on android 7.0

Comment: Do you request permissions for reading external storage?

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you request permissions for reading external storage?

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Let set permission inside your phone. It worked for me [image]